# Finding all instances that match value within json stored in Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a table "Transfer" in my database. In this table transfer I have a column "archive" in which I store a Json object.
 So I have something like that:

```
archive:{
       "AuthorId"=>"6621381"
        }
```

My goal is to find all the transfers where  "AuthorId"=>"6621381". Is it possible to do that with rails ?
Something that looks like:

```
 Transfer.where(archive: {"AuthorId" => "6621381"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator to access the object field as text :

```
Transfer.where("archive ->> 'AuthorId' = ?", "123")    

=> [0] #<Transfer:0x00000002903a60> {
    :archive => {
      "AuthorId" => "123"
    }
  }
]
```

It also works with other operators, such as `LIKE`/`ILIKE` :

```
Transfer.where("archive ->> 'AuthorId' ILIKE ?", "12%")

=> [
  [0] #<Transfer:0x00000002893058> {
    :archive => {
      "AuthorId" => "123"
    }
  },
  [1] #<Transfer:0x00000002892c98> {
    :archive => {
      "AuthorId" => "124"
    }
  }
]
```